# How to add JSON header

Tags: android, json, android-volley

My code to sent `JSONArray` to server...

```
   StringRequest request= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            public Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                getResults().put(parameters);
                return parameters;


            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

This code is used to sent `JSONArray` to the server. How can I set a header so the the server can identify that its a JSON file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpliest way to set the `Content-Type` header field of your `Request` might be to override `getBodyContentType()`:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json";
}
```

If you would like to send JSON in the body of your POST request, you should use either `JsonObjectRequest` or `JsonArrayRequest`.

For example, if your `getResults()` method returns a `JSONArray` that you would like to send as the body of the request, you could do something like this:

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        serverUrl, getResults(),
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // handle the response
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // an error occurred
            }
        });

requestQueue.add(request);
```